# Console.log from a class' function

Tags: javascript, class, testing, subclass, console.log

I want to test if my function inside my class returns the given sentence. But if I try to test using `console.log`, it returns `ReferenceError: rev is not defined`. What am I doing wrong?

```
class store {
    constructor(revenue, workers) {
        this.revenue = revenue;
        this.workers = workers;
    }
}

class storeManager extends store {
    constructor(name) {
        super(revenue, workers);
        this.name = name;
    }

    rev() {
        return "The stores revenue is" + this.revenue;
    }
  
    hiredWorkers() {
        return "The store has" + this.revenue + "workers";
    }
};

console.log(rev())
```

I'm a fairly new programmer, so bear with me if this is a stupid question.

Comment: `console.log(rev())` -> `console.log(new storeManager("some name").rev())`

Comment: `rev` is a method in your `class` which would be called from an instance of your `class`, eg. `const obj = new storeManager(...); console.log(obj.rev());`

Comment: Since you're new: In JavaScript, the overwhelmingly-common (and standard) way to name constructor functions (including ones defined via `class` syntax) is to use an initial uppercase character. So `Store` and `StoreManager` rather than `store` and `storeManager`. Although you don't have to do that, doing it makes it easier for others (including people here) to understand your code.

Comment: Side note: You don't put `;` after `class` *declarations* like yours above, only after an assignment using a class *expression* (for instance, `const x = class { /*... */ };`). But *do* include `;` to terminate statements like `console.log(rev())` above. (In that particular case, if you don't, automatic semicolon insertion will usually do it for you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire point of a class is to provide a template to bundle up functionality into a self-contained object and **not** have globals for everything.

`rev` is a *method* that appears on *instances* of the class. It isn't a global.

You have to create an instance of the class:

```
const myInstance = new StoreManager("some value for name");
```

(Note that this is going to fail because your constructor calls `super()` and tried to pass the values of variables which don't exist in the constructor method).

… and then call the method on that:

```
const result = myInstance.rev();
```